# http url-encoding mechanism

Tags: http, servlets, web, urlencode

In my understanding by default browsers encode reserved characters and
non-alphanumeric characters with three bytes/characters:

```
        `%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal    
         digits representing the ASCII code of the character.
```

So on server side lets say
**queryString** is the query string before decoding
and :

```
decodedQueryString = URLDecoder.decode(queryString , "Utf-8");
```

at this point the value of the expression:

```
decodedQueryString.length() < queryString.length();
```

should usually be **true** , am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost. If the undecoded query string doesn't contain any escaped characters, the lengths will be equal. I can't think of any case where, after decoding, the query string would be longer.